# Random nvarchar(255) id as primary key in SQLite

Tags: text, sqlite, primary-key, nvarchar

I am creating a SQLite database which uses an id field as the primary key. Is it possible to create an automatic id which is equivalent to a random nvarchar(255) string?

I need it this way because later on I replace this pre-existing database with one being populated by a web service and the default value for id is (CONVERT(nvarchar,newid(),(0))).

I am using the SQLite3 shell for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, an [automatically generated ID](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) must be a 64-bit integer.

Values of any other data type must be generated manually.